Check function is parametrization of hyperbolic paraboloid from Do Carmo's "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces"
In Do Carmo's "Differential Geometry of Curves and Surfaces" , there is the following (adapted) exercise:

Exercise 2-2, 11. Show that the set $S =\{(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{R}^3;z = x^2−y^2\}$ is a regular surface and check that this function is a parametrization for $S$:
$$\mathbf{x}(u,v) = (u\cosh v,u\sinh v,u^2),\;(u,v) \in \mathbb{R}^2,\;u \neq0.$$
Which parts of $S$ does this parametrization cover?

Checking that it's a regular surface is easy, however I'm not sure how to show it's a parametrization, since in other exercises I tried solving a system of equations to show the function maps to the surface, but since it involves $\sinh v$ and $\cosh v$, I got stuck.
I tried writing them down in terms of exponentials to little success. I've found another question that covers the same exercise but there it says that showing it's a parametrization is easy, which made me wonder if I'm overthinking this.
Would it just be because $u^2 \cosh^2 v - u^2 \sinh^2 v = u^2$, and therefore cover just the positive $z$-axis part of the surface because of $u^2$ in the third coordinate?

Would it just be because...  yes, that's all. However, not the whole thing, as $u^2 \geq 0$ while $z$ is negative half the time

Thanks for the verification, I actually just had to type it to get it

You almost got what you wanted just by typing out the Query in the right way. I jut want to fill in some missing things , while clarifying some things.
(1) Showing that the set $S$ is a regular surface is easy , just using the Definitions.
(2) Showing that $(x,y,z)=(u \cosh v , u \sinh v , u^2)$ is a Parametrization is just what you already got & what Will Jagy confirmed.
We have to check that $z=x^2-y^2$ , which is going to give $u^2=[u \cosh v]^2-[u \sinh v]^2$
(3) Which parts of $S$ does this Parametrization cover?
"... Cover just the positive $z-axis$ part of the surface ..."
That is true , though not the "Direct Way" state it.
Consider the $XY-Plane$ , where the Shaded Area has $|x| \ge |y|$ ( the Boundary is $x=\pm y$ )

While $S$ is available all over the Plane , for all $(x,y)$ tuples , the Parametrization is available only over $|x| \ge |y|$
It just so happens that this gives Positive $z$ values in Current Case.
(4) What about covering the half where $|x| \le |y|$ ?
We can then try the Parametrization with $(x,y,z)=(u \sinh v , u \cosh v , -u^2)$ which will give the other half.
Parametrization is now available only over $|x| \le |y|$
